# INSERT INTO multiple tables using LAST_INSERT_ID inside PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

I am aware that there are quite a few Q&As for this topic but I am facing quite an individual problem, which is why I raised a new question.

I am using `PHP7` with `mariadb 10.x` and the `PHP` templating engine `Twig 2.x`.
**My goal is to insert data into 2 related tables (adresse, person).**

For those of you who are unfamiliar with `Twig`, it is basically a tool which helps separating `html` and `php` code by using templates. My `.html` files are therefore called `.twig`.

If I use the following code, the `INSERT INTO` only fills `adresse` with values but `person` remains completely empty. There is no error message in `error.log`.
**What am I missing? What did I do wrong?**

I also added `BEGIN; --preparestmt--; COMMIT;` to make sure that this statement belongs together and should be treated as one transaction.

I typed `SELECT last_insert_id();` and it gave me the result `0`. Why?

`adresse.adresse_id` did increment after all? Why does `last_insert_id()` not take the incremented value but `0`?

My *table structure*:

## adresse

- adresse_id (INT, PK, NOT NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT)
- name1
- strasse
- plz
- ort

## person

- person_id (INT, PRIMARY KEY, NOT NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT)
- adresse_id (FK)
- adrgruppe_id
- adrstatus_id
- funktion_id
- name
- vorname
- funktion
- abteilung
- telefon
- telefon2
- telefon3
- telefon4
- mailadresse
- fax
- sb_kuerzel

## neuerBauleiter.twig

```
{% include "headerKundendienst.twig" %}
<body class="maincontent">
    <div class="main-content">
    <h2>Bauleiter hinzufügen</h2>
        <form method="post" action="neuerBauleiter">

                <p>
                    <label class="editSupplierLabel">Nachname</label>
                    <input class="editSupplier" type="text" name="txtBlName" required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="editSupplierLabel">Vorname</label>
                    <input class="editSupplier" type="text" name="txtBlVorname" required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="editSupplierLabel">Anschrift</label>
                    <input class="editSupplier" type="text" name="txtBlAnschrift" required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="editSupplierLabel">PLZ</label>
                    <input class="editSupplier" type="text" name="txtBlPlz" required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="editSupplierLabel">Ort</label>
                    <input class="editSupplier" type="text" name="txtBlOrt" required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="editSupplierLabel">Telefon</label>
                    <input class="editSupplier" type="tel" name="txtBlTel" required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="editSupplierLabel">Telefon2</label>
                    <input class="editSupplier" type="tel" name="txtBlTel2">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="editSupplierLabel">Telefon3</label>
                    <input class="editSupplier" type="tel" name="txtBlTel3">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="editSupplierLabel">E-Mail</label>
                    <input class="editSupplier" type="email" name="txtBlMail" required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="editSupplierLabel">Fax</label>
                    <input class="editSupplier" type="tel" name="txtBlFax">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="editSupplierLabel">Sachbearbeiter</label>
                    <input class="editSupplier" type="text" name="txtBlSb" value="{{ loggedUser }}" readonly required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="editSupplierLabel">Adressgruppe-ID</label>
                    <input class="editSupplier" type="text" name="BlAdrgruppeid" value="1272" readonly required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="editSupplierLabel">Adressstatus-ID</label>
                    <input class="editSupplier" type="text" name="BlAdrstatusid" value="62" readonly required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="editSupplierLabel">Funktion-ID</label>
                    <input class="editSupplier" type="text" name="BlFunktionid" value="2" readonly required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="editSupplierLabel">Funktion</label>
                    <input class="editSupplier" type="text" name="BlFunktion" value="Bauleiter" readonly required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="editSupplierLabel">Abteilung</label>
                    <input class="editSupplier" type="text" name="BlAbteilung" value="Bauleitung" readonly required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input class="button_save" type="submit" name="btnSaveBl" value="Speichern">
                    <a href="listeBauleiter" class="button_delete" style="margin-bottom: 40px; margin-left:150px;">Zur&uuml;ck</a>
                </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
{% include "footer.twig" %}
```

## neuerBauleiter.php

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // keine pfad anpassung mehr nötig, immer so lassen
require_once "utils/Database.class.php"; // include database configuration

/* Daten für neuen Bauleiter speichern */
if (isset($_POST["btnSaveBl"])) 
{

DatabaseLink::getInstance()->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$stmt = DatabaseLink::getInstance()->prepare("INSERT INTO adresse(name1, strasse, plz, ort) 
VALUES (:blNachname, :blAnschrift, :blPlz, :blOrt);
INSERT INTO intranet.person(adresse_id, name, vorname, 
telefon, telefon2, telefon4, mailadresse, fax, adrgruppe_id, adrstatus_id, funktion_id, funktion, abteilung, sb_kuerzel)
VALUES (last_insert_id(), :blNachname, :blVorname, 
:blTel, :blTel2, :blTel4, :blMail, :blFax, :bladrgruppeid, :bladrstatusid, :blfunktionid, :blfunktion, 
:blabteilung, :blSachbearbeiter;)");

$result = $stmt->execute(array(
        ":blNachname" => $_POST["txtBlName"],
        ":blVorname" => $_POST["txtBlVorname"],
        ":blAnschrift" => $_POST["txtBlAnschrift"],
        ":blPlz" => $_POST["txtBlPlz"],
    ":blOrt" => $_POST["txtBlOrt"],
    ":blTel" => $_POST["txtBlTel"],
    ":blTel2" => $_POST["txtBlTel2"],
    ":blTel4" => $_POST["txtBlTel3"],
    ":blMail" => $_POST["txtBlMail"],
    ":blFax" => $_POST["txtBlFax"],
    ":blSachbearbeiter" => $_POST["txtBlSb"],
    ":bladrgruppeid" => $_POST["BlAdrgruppeid"], 
    ":bladrstatusid" => $_POST["BlAdrstatusid"],
    ":blfunktionid" => $_POST["BlFunktionid"], 
    ":blfunktion" => $_POST["BlFunktion"],
    ":blabteilung" => $_POST["BlAbteilung"] 
));



    header("Location: listeBauleiter");
}

/* Twig initialisieren */
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('template/'); // keine pfad anpassung mehr nötig, immer so lassen
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    "debug" => "true",
));
include "utils/injector.php";

$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
//templatewerte
$templateName = "neuerBauleiter.twig";

$data = array(

);

//display
echo $twig->render($templateName, $data);
```

Comment: Put last_id in a variable then insert using that variable. last_id doesnt stay forever.

Comment: I would break this into 2 SQL statements and run them separately, make it easier to see if there are problems.

Comment: @NkoleEvans : Could you be a bit more precise by showing me how to do that in my example, please? I don't understand where and how I need to make these changes and how the code looks like afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot put multiple statements in a prepared query. From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

> SQL syntax for prepared statements does not support multi-statements

So you will need to split your prepare and execute into 2 as below. You should find this then means that `LAST_INSERT_ID()` starts working as you expect.

```
$stmt = DatabaseLink::getInstance()->prepare("INSERT INTO adresse(name1, strasse, plz, ort) 
VALUES (:blNachname, :blAnschrift, :blPlz, :blOrt)");
$stmt2 = DatabaseLink::getInstance()->prepare("INSERT INTO intranet.person(adresse_id, name, vorname, 
telefon, telefon2, telefon4, mailadresse, fax, adrgruppe_id, adrstatus_id, funktion_id, funktion, abteilung, sb_kuerzel)
VALUES (last_insert_id(), :blNachname, :blVorname, :blTel, :blTel2, :blTel4, :blMail, :blFax, :bladrgruppeid, :bladrstatusid, :blfunktionid, :blfunktion, 
:blabteilung, :blSachbearbeiter;)");

$result = $stmt->execute(array(
        ":blNachname" => $_POST["txtBlName"],
        ":blVorname" => $_POST["txtBlVorname"],
        ":blAnschrift" => $_POST["txtBlAnschrift"],
        ":blPlz" => $_POST["txtBlPlz"],
        ":blOrt" => $_POST["txtBlOrt"]));

$result2 = $stmt2->execute(array(
    ":blTel" => $_POST["txtBlTel"],
    ":blTel2" => $_POST["txtBlTel2"],
    ":blTel4" => $_POST["txtBlTel3"],
    ":blMail" => $_POST["txtBlMail"],
    ":blFax" => $_POST["txtBlFax"],
    ":blSachbearbeiter" => $_POST["txtBlSb"],
    ":bladrgruppeid" => $_POST["BlAdrgruppeid"], 
    ":bladrstatusid" => $_POST["BlAdrstatusid"],
    ":blfunktionid" => $_POST["BlFunktionid"], 
    ":blfunktion" => $_POST["BlFunktion"],
    ":blabteilung" => $_POST["BlAbteilung"] 
));
```

Comment: Thank you, Nick. This solved the issue for me. However, I am certain that 2 statements inside PDO prepare can work, too because I tested it 3 months ago with another pair of php-twig and it worked. But I believe that multiple selects from too many users will make your database break down if you keep these kinds of prepare-statements. A stricter transaction level might be more stable and secure in this example.But then again I have no idea how good practice looks like if you have let's say 100 users querying the database like crazy. ?!

Comment: Hi @timunix it is possible that it could work if prepared statements were being emulated. PDO on its own is quite happy to execute multiple statements in one query and if prepared statements were being emulated then this wouldn't violate that. Note that using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` like this is safe even with multiple users as [MySQL maintains that value on a per-client basis](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) for just that reason.